AzureDevOps 'Release' tab not visible - What Permissions Are Needed
Under our Pipelines tab, I'm unable to view the option to create a 'Release Pipeline', see image. Can someone let me know what needs to be granted in order to view the 'Release pipeline' tab?

@Rui, I followed the documentation. After creating my pipeline, I followed the documentation. After Step 2 I see I have the following permissions:

Does the permissions suggest I don't have the permissions to create a Release pipeline?

Hi @Patterson, have you checked my answer below and disabled Disable creation of classic release pipelines in your pipeline settings? Can you see the Release tab now？

According to the documentation, Project Administrators and Release Administrators are granted all release management permissions.
You can find a list of permissions for releases and whether the permission can be set at the project, release pipeline, or stage level in Release permissions reference.
PS: Keep in mind that in order to create release pipelines you need to disable the Disable creation of classic release pipelines toggle, as mentioned in my other answer.

thanks again for reaching out. So are you saying that if Disable creation of classic release pipelines  is 'not' enabled, you won't see the 'Releases' tab even if you are a member of Project Administrators or Release Administrators?

Note sure, that's something that you'll have to check. I'll rephrase the last sentence of my answer :-)

I have updated the question after checking my permissions as suggested in the documentation you provided

To create release pipelines, ensure Disable creation of classic release pipelines is disabled in your project. Go to Project Settings -> Settings under Pipelines -> Turn off Disable creation of classic release pipelines.

According to the blog,

If you turned on the toggle to Disable creation of classic build and classic release pipelines, then no classic build pipeline, classic release pipeline, task groups, and deployment groups can be created.


The user interface will not show the Releases, Task groups, and Deployment groups left-side menu items if you have none of them.

Once "Disable creation of classic release pipelines" is enabled, no matter what permissions you have, you will not be able to see the Release menu item on the UI, even if you are a Project Collection Administrator.
